# Why does the button stay enabled although CanExecute of bound command is false

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a ViewModel with an `ICommand`:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public bool CanExecute { get; set; }

    public ICommand SomeCommand { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CanExecute = true;

        SomeCommand = new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show("Executing"), () => CanExecute);

        CommandManager.RequerySuggested += OnRefreshing;
    }

    private void OnRefreshing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Refreshing");
    }
}
```

And I have a very simple binding to it in my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding CanExecute, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Click Me!" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I click on the CheckBox, CanExecute should change. I can see that `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` is thrown, but my button stays enabled.

What's wrong? My binding? Does this have anything to do with MVVMLight?

Comment: Does your command trigger `CanExecuteChanged`?

Comment: @ChrFin: Oh! No, it actually doesn't! I relied on RelayCommand to do that for me.

Comment: How should it know about it? You just supply `() => CanExecute` to it - no way to get notified about a change on that property...

Comment: I was under the impression that RelayCommand listens to CommandManager.RequerySuggested and would do that for me. Obviously it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the MVVMLight framework. Its `RelayCommand` was changed and does not listen to `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` any more. So you actually have to manually call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` on the command. This sucks...

See [here](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7546) for a discussion on this change in MVVMLight.

Any idea, how to handle this without a ton of manual calls to `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `RequerySuggested` kinda sucked to begin with.  "One button's state changes?  Let's check every ICommand binding in the UI!"

Comment: Call RaiseCanExecuteChanged whenever the state which CanExecute depends on changes (this is the only clean way to do it...)